# what is the interactive REPL IO function?

Tags: io, common-lisp, read-eval-print-loop

I have been learning Common Lisp for a while, there was a question I have met that 
how I can implement such a function which allows user to input some words until user input exit.
(actually I want to know what kind of command line interactive function APIs fit such requirement)

e.g.
prompt "please input a word: " in the REPL, then store user inputs into a global   *my-words* , exit when user input "exit".

Comment: This is unclear to me. Do you want to read a  single line of input (terminate when user presses return), why do you need a global *my-words* variable?  Please add details about why you need this and what you did try. Thanks

Comment: yes, terminate when user press return,

Comment: actually, I just want to write a sample the used for collecting words, for testing only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CL-USER 23 > (progn
               (format t "~%enter a list of words:~%")
               (finish-output)
               (setf my-words (read))
               (terpri))

enter a list of words:
(foo bar baz)
```

or

```
CL-USER 28 > (loop with word = nil

                   do
                   (format t "~%enter a word or exit:~%")
                   (finish-output)

                   (setf word (read))
                   (terpri)

                   until (eql word 'exit)

                   collect word)

enter a word or exit:
foo


enter a word or exit:
bar


enter a word or exit:
baz


enter a word or exit:
exit

(FOO BAR BAZ)
```

Comment: that is exactly what I expected, thanks for your kindness.

Answer (score 5):

You specification is a little bit incomplete (e.g. what constitutes a word in your problem? What if the user add multiple words? What if the input is empty?). Here below I am using [CL-PPCRE](http://weitz.de/cl-ppcre/) to split the input into different words and add them all at once, because it seems useful in general. In your case you might want to add more error checking.

If you want to interact with the user, you should read and write from and to the [`*QUERY-IO*`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/v_debug_.htm) stream. Here I'll present a version with a global variables, as you requested, as well as another one without side-effects (apart from input/output).

### With a global variable

Define the global variable and initialize it with an empty adjustable array.
I am  using an array so that it is easy to add words at the end, but you could also use a queue.

```lisp
(defvar *my-words* (make-array 10 :fill-pointer 0 :adjustable t))
```

The following function mutates the global variable:

```lisp
(defun side-effect-word-repl ()
  (loop
     (format *query-io* "~&Please input a word: ")
     (finish-output *query-io*)
     (let ((words (ppcre:split
                   '(:greedy-repetition 1 nil :whitespace-char-class)
                   (read-line *query-io*))))
       (dolist (w words)
         (when (string-equal w "exit") ; ignore case
           (return-from side-effect-word-repl))
         (vector-push-extend w *my-words*)))))
```

- The [`LOOP`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/m_loop.htm) uses the simple syntax where there are only expressions and no *loop*-specific keywords. I first write the prompt to `*QUERY-IO*`. The `~&` [`FORMAT`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/f_format.htm) directive performs the same operation as [`FRESH-LINE`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/f_terpri.htm). As Rainer pointed out in comments, we have to call [`FINISH-OUTPUT`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/f_finish.htm) to ensure the message is effectively printed before the user is expected to reply.
- Then, I read a whole line from the same bidirectional stream, and split it into a list of words, where a word is a string of non-whitespace characters.
- With [`DOLIST`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/m_dolist.htm), I iterate over the list and add words into the global array with [`VECTOR-PUSH-EXTEND`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/f_vec_ps.htm). But as soon as I encouter `"exit"`, I terminate the loop; since I rely on [`STRING-EQUAL`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/f_stgeq_.htm), the test is done case-insensitively.

### Side-effect free approach

Having a global variable as done above is discouraged. If you only need to have a prompt which *returns* a list of words, then the following will be enough. Here, I use the [`PUSH`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/m_push.htm)/[`NREVERSE`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/f_revers.htm) idiom to built the resulting list of words.

```lisp
(defun pure-word-repl ()
  (let ((result '()))
    (loop
       (format *query-io* "~&Please input a word: ")
       (finish-output *query-io*)
       (let ((words (ppcre:split
                     '(:greedy-repetition 1 nil :whitespace-char-class)
                     (read-line *query-io*))))
         (dolist (w words)
           (when (string-equal w "exit")
             (return-from pure-word-repl (nreverse result)))
           (push w result))))))
```

### Note about words

As jkiiski commented, it might be better to split words at `:word-boundary`. I tried different combinations and the following result seems satisfying with weird example strings:

```lisp
(mapcan (lambda (string) 
          (ppcre:split :word-boundary string)) 
  (ppcre:split
    '(:greedy-repetition 1 nil :whitespace-char-class)
  "amzldk           'amlzkd d;:azdl azdlk"))

=>  ("amzldk" "'" "amlzkd" "d" ";:" "azdl" "azdlk")
```

I first remove all whitespaces and split the string into a list of strings, which can contain punctuation marks. Then, each string is itself splitted at `:word-boundary`, and concatenated with [`MAPCAN`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/f_mapc_.htm) to form a list of separate words. However, I can't really guess what your actual needs are, so you should probably define your own `SPLIT-INTO-WORDS` function to validate and split an input string.

Comment: You could loop over the words with `(ppcre:do-matches-as-strings (w "\\w+" (read-line *query-io*)) ...)` instead of splitting at whitespaces, so that punctuation marks aren't taken as a part of the word.

Comment: Don't forget to display the output before expecting an answer - in case the output stream is buffered...

Comment: @RainerJoswig Thanks, I tend to forget that.

Comment: my apologies, I didn't describe my purpose clearly, but you did give very good answers and comments which also helped me,  really appreciate that !!!